# How do I create a multimedia shortcut on a keyboard without multimedia keys?

Tags: shortcuts, multimedia

Is it possible to make a shortcut for the multimedia keys on any other key? In my case I have only the volume keys on my keyboard, no other keys like e.g. to skip songs. Can we have a  shorcut to skip a song on another key, or for example on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Vol</kbd> key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! If you are using `banshee`, Open the keyboard preferences. Click on the second tab named "Shortcuts".
In the left pane, click on custom shortcuts. Click on + sign:

In name put:

```
Music next
```

In command put:

```
banshee --next
```

Now in the right pane click and put your own accelerator for this.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: I already make that for the Banshee, but I want to make in other player (Nuvola Player). If is possible to make an secondary shortcut will be alot easier.

Comment: I can be of help if you post the man page of that player. [couldn't find it on internet]

Comment: https://launchpad.net/nuvola-player

The developer says in the next release will have the 'nuvolaplayer --next' feature. But anyway, I was trying to make an secondary shorcut for 'next song' multimedia keyboard because in that way will work with everything.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small tutorial that intros this principle by using AutoHotkey: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoDfCiKoBCk

Comment: Great to see that you have created a tutorial on this, hopefully it will help and solve the original question.

Comment: Thank you. It's for Windows 10, maybe people looking for a similar solution in Windows might find this useful.